# How to scroll fixed area when footer is reached?

Tags: css

Is it possible to achive the following configuration in CSS please ?

- I have a long page with a footer in the bottom (the footer display property is flex)
- In the visible area of the page I need the fixed area to be always in the bottom as long as the scrolling has not reached the footer.
- Once the scrolling has reached the footer, the fixed area should scroll up to be on the top of the footer like in the following screenshots:

[image]

1. The fixed area is in the bottom of the visible region of the page.
2. When scrolling, if the footer is not reached, the fixed are will remain at the bottom of the page
3. When reaching the footer, the fixed position is on the top of the footer

I tried something like:

```
FixedArea {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

but when I scroll until the footer the fixed region disappears.

Answer (score 2):

You can nest the body content together with the fixed content in a element that has a `height: 100vh` on it, and `overflow: auto` on the actual content of that page, in that way the content will scroll independently of the fix element, and once reached the end the body scroll will continue on till the end of page (footer)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (another) possible jQuery solution.

During scroll, calculate the distance remaining until the bottom of the window, and start setting the `bottom` style property on your fixed area the height of the footer minus the distance remaining, otherwise make sure it's set (back) to the original, as follows (note, I set the height of the content block to 800px, so make sure you try this so that the result window has a smaller height than that):

```js
var originalBottom = 0; // get this depending on your circumstances
var footerHeight = 72; // get this depending on your circumstances
$(window).scroll(function () { // start to scroll
  // calculating the distance from bottom
  var distanceToBottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop();
  if (distanceToBottom <= footerHeight) // when reaching the footer
    $("#fixed-area").css('bottom', (footerHeight - distanceToBottom) + 'px');
  else // when distancing from the footer
    $("#fixed-area").css('bottom', originalBottom + 'px'); // only need to specify 'px' (or other unit) if the number is not 0
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  height: 800px;
}

#fixed-area {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: calc(100% - 22px); /* padding (2*5) + border (2*1) + margin (2*5) */
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="fixed-area">Fixed Area</div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created an example. Try: https://jsfiddle.net/pvviana/wwc8LgLm/

I am changing the div css property "position" at the bottom of page.

Code:

```
<div class="foo">Hello</div>
<footer>OKAY</footer>
```

Javascript(Jquery):

```
var $logo = $('.foo');
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $logo.css({position: $(this).scrollTop()>100 ? "relative":"fixed"});
});
```

Css :

```
.foo {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;   
}
```

Comment: How about something not with jquery?

Comment: You're calculating the distance from the top, whereas you should calculate it from the bottom for this to be scalable.